# Cannot build openshift persistent with web-console

Tags: openshift, openshift-web-console

I try to build mysql persistent on openshift with web consoles. When I build wildfly pod on openshift, it works successfully. But try of mysql and mariadb failed. I have no idea why building pods of openshift persistent failed.

Below are the log contents:

```
--> Scaling mysql-1 to 1
--> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in deployment mysql-1 to become ready
W0325 10:19:37.240002 1 reflector.go:330] github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/strategy/support/lifecycle.go:468: watch of *api.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 1037954500 (1037974842)
error: update acceptor rejected mysql-1: pods for deployment "mysql-1" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

I can not understand this error message. I chose minimum option on web consoles when generate mysql and mariadb containers. Do you think I miss the critical option?

**UPDATE**

I try every efforts to deploy every kinds of persistent database including mariadb and mysql. However the above same error log messages. Do I miss some critical procedure? For your information, Below is the mysql deploy message:

```
Failed sync     Error syncing pod, skipping: error killing pod: failed to "TeardownNetwork" for "mysql-1-deploy_josephopenshiftproject" with TeardownNetworkError: "Failed to teardown network for pod \"efe80474-15d2-11e7-9f88-0e63b9c1c48f\" using network plugins \"cni\": CNI request failed with status 400: 'Failed to ensure that nat chain POSTROUTING jumps to MASQUERADE: error checking rule: exit status 4: iptables: Resource temporarily unavailable.\n\n'"
```

Comment: Post the log from your pod, this is from the deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All log generated from my pod is below,  W0331 00:11:10.190202       1 reflector.go:330] github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/strategy/support/lifecycle.go:468: watch of *api.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 1061176152 (1061192878)
error: update acceptor rejected mysql-1: pods for deployment "mysql-1" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready    Any idea?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 pro 64bit. I am afraid my configuration was a mess. I reinstall my os and it works well. I hope this would be helpful to who are facing the similar issues like mine. Thanks any way.